# Watchdog observer not running in container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, python-watchdog

I am using [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/%22watchdog%22) to monitor a file directory for filesystem events. If this **watcher** script detects an event, I want to make an entry in a database (in this case Mongodb). The file system to be watched is actually a Docker volume linking its filesystem to my host pc's. All code is running in docker containers. I can attach to any of the containers in the system and use pymongo to correctly add an entry to the db.

I can also run the **watcher** on the host machine and all works as expected (including acting as expected if there is a change to the filesystem from the linked filesystem in a container.

*However when I run the watcher code in a container, the methods in the event handler triggered by filesystem events never seems to be called. There are certainly no db entries created.*

There are 3 sources of code:

1. The watchdog directory 'watcher' including a watcher and a handler **[watchdog_classes]**

   ```
   import time
   from watchdog.observers import Observer
   import watchdog.events as events
   from data_persist import persistance_interface

   db_interface= persistance_interface()

   class RepoWatcher:



      def __init__(self, dir_root='/targer_dir/'):
           print(dir_root)
           self.observer = Observer()
           self.dir_root = dir_root

       def run(self):
           event_handler = CustomEventHandler()
           self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.dir_root, recursive=True)
           self.observer.start()
           try:
               while True:
                   time.sleep(5)
           except KeyboardInterrupt:
               self.observer.stop()
               print("Shutting down...")

           self.observer.join()

   class CustomEventHandler(events.FileSystemEventHandler):
       @staticmethod
       def on_any_event(event):

           # Renamed files or dirs
           if isinstance(event, events.FileSystemMovedEvent):
               print("moved")
               db_interface.persist_one({'rename': 'renamed'})

           # Created files or dirs
           elif event.event_type == 'created':
               print("created")
               db_interface.persist_one({'create': 'creation'})

           # Deleted files or dirs
           elif isinstance(event, events.FileDeletedEvent):
               print("deleted")
               db_interface.persist_one({'deletion': 'deleted'})
   ```
2. A class used to write to Mongodb **[data_persist module]**

   ```
   import pymongo
   from pymongo import MongoClient

   class persistance_interface():
       def __init__(self):
       self.client = MongoClient('db', 27017)
       self.db = self.client.filesystemeventsdb
       self.filesystemevents_collection = self.db.filesystemevents_collection

   def persist_one(self, data):
       self.asset_collection.insert_one(data)
   ```
3. A script which triggers the watcher **[watcher.py]**

   ```
   import watchdog_classes

   watcher = watchdog_classes.RepoWatcher()
   watcher.run()
   ```

I am running the 3 code sources in the same Docker container, the mongodb is in another container.

The docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    image: tutum/mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - AUTH=no
    entrypoint: "usr/bin/mongod"

  sentry:
    build: ./Docker/sentry
    entrypoint: "python -u run_watcher.py"
    volumes:
      - "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\HostVolume:/Container_Volume"

  web:
    build: ./Docker/site
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python -u manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\HostVolume:/Container_Volume"
```

> Why are the watchdog handler events not being called?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the source of my issue lied not within my code but **Docker for windows does not notify container about any file changes you make from Windows**. That means that only changes made to the volume from within the container are visible to it.

I found a workaround [here](http://blog.subjectify.us/miscellaneous/2017/04/24/docker-for-windows-watch-bindings.html), though it requires a that the host directory runs a script continuously. Not ideal but at least for not it works.